# expo eject error - the system cannot find the path specified

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, expo

I am trying to run the `expo eject` command in my project directory, the command seems to work fine up until it gets to the "Applying iOS configuration" stage.

At the point, it provides me with the following error and abandons the expo ejecting process;

The system cannot find the path specified. spawn /bin/cp ENOENT

`Error: spawn /bin/cp ENOENT at notFoundError`

`(C:\\Users\*\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node\_modules\\expo-cli\\node\_modules\\cross-spawn\\lib\\enoent.js:6:26) at verifyENOENT (C:\\Users\*\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node\_modules\\expo-cli\\node\_modules\\cross-spawn\\lib\\enoent.js:40:16) at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\\Users\*\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node\_modules\\expo-cli\\node\_modules\\cross-spawn\\lib\\enoent.js:27:25) at Process.ChildProcess.\_handle.onexit (internal/child\_process.js:272:12)`

Comment: Please don't use `expo eject` it doesn't at all work as expected. I'm commenting this based on my personal experience. It is best to convert/copy all your logic and setup a new `react-native` project from stratch. (It won't take much time as expected). You can mail me at sagarvk539@gmail.com and I'll be glad to help you!

Comment: So what's so bad with `expo eject`? I have a medium-sized project that I want to publish to the app store sometime soon and think this will take too much time to do. I hear expo is a great tool for publishing and ejecting.

Comment: Yes, I understood but all I was saying is `expo eject` didn't at all work for me !

Answer (score 0):

Maybe updating your expo-cli may fix it

`npm install -g expo-cli`